# How do I get everything after tab in text file?

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, text

I have a text file i am trying to isolate everything after the tab. How do I do that

Before:

```
GSVIVT01034325001_1 GATTTCAAAAGCATTCTGTTGTTCTTTGAGGTCAGCAACCTGACCAATAAAAA
GSVIVT01034326001_2 TACGCTTGACAAGACGTCTCCATGTCCTTTCAAGCGACTTGCTACGCTATGCACCATGC
GSVIVT01034329001_3 AAAATTGGATGCATAAAACAAAATAAATGTAAATACTAAAATAATGATCATATTCTTACCTTAATCCGT
```

After:

```
GATTTCAAAAGCATTCTGTTGTTCTTTGAGGTCAGCAACCTGACCAATAAAAA
TACGCTTGACAAGACGTCTCCATGTCCTTTCAAGCGACTTGCTACGCTATGCACCATGC
AAAATTGGATGCATAAAACAAAATAAATGTAAATACTAAAATAATGATCATATTCTTACCTTAATCCGT
```

```
fhandle: IO = open("seqs.txt","r")
list_of_let: List[str] = []

for items in fhandle:
    spltl: List[str] = items.split("\t")
    new_let: str = str(spltl[0])
    list_of_let.append(new_let)
print(list_of_let)
```

Comment: Try to use proper grammer when posting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split()`. You don't have to specify the `\t` char, split will automatically work with whitespaces:

```py
with open('your file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        # skip empty lines:
        if line == "":
            continue
        _, part_2 = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        print(part_2)
```

Prints:

```
GATTTCAAAAGCATTCTGTTGTTCTTTGAGGTCAGCAACCTGACCAATAAAAA
TACGCTTGACAAGACGTCTCCATGTCCTTTCAAGCGACTTGCTACGCTATGCACCATGC
AAAATTGGATGCATAAAACAAAATAAATGTAAATACTAAAATAATGATCATATTCTTACCTTAATCCGT
```